# Bash check java version - not comparing strings properly

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

Can anyone see what I have done wrong here?

```
local VERSION=$(java -version 2>&1 | grep "java version")
if [[ ! "$VERSION" =~ *"1.8.0_33"* ]]; then
  ERROR (not code, just place holder)
else
  NO ERROR (not code, just place holder)
fi
```

Thanks for the quick help!

*** UPDATE ***

Here is what else I have tried:

```
local VERSION=$(java -version 2>&1 | grep "java version")
if [[ "$VERSION" != *"1.8.0_33"* ]];  then
  Error blah blah not using 1.8.0_33
else
  Good to go
fi
```

This is in a function all by itself. No other nested anything.

GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)

Comment: Just use: `[[ "$VERSION" != *"1.8.0_33"* ]]`

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well wth no luck it seems

Comment: Have you actually looked to see what `$VERSION` contains?

Comment: What does `echo "[$VERSION]"` show to you?

Comment: Hmm interesting. Version appears to be empty... I have used this method many times in same program though with success. Something weird is going on.

Comment: In fact, java -version 2>&1 | grep "java version" at the command line works just fine. It outputs exactly like expected, but for some reason doesnt appear to be saving to VERSION

Comment: Tried different variable name too in case there was a conflict

Comment: Is `java` on `$PATH` when you execute the script?

Comment: java path is set in .bashrc and works great by itself ie java-version outputs: java version "1.8.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_33-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.33-b05, mixed mode) and java -version 2>&1 | grep "java version" outputs java version "1.8.0_33"

Comment: If you just stick that command in the script by itself (not in that assignment) do you see it output the version information to the screen correctly?

Comment: Hmm no. $(command) doesnt appear to be working

Comment: echo $(pwd) works, but $(java -version 2>&1 | grep "java version") is coming up blank.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `VERSION` (you shouldn't use ALL_CAPS variables by the way, those are "reserved" for shell/etc. usage) is the *entire line* that matches 'java version'.

That isn't going to ever match a simple version string.

You need to pull out just the version from the matching line if you want to do something like this.

The RHS of `=~` is a regex not a glob. That is you need `.*` not `*` to match anything.

Or, as anubhava correctly points out, you can use `[[` globbing with `!=` directly.

```
[[ "$VERSION" != *"\"1.8.0_33\""* ]]
```

I added escaped quotes to the match since the output from `java -version` appears to have them and otherwise this would also match `1.8.0_333`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep`:

```
VERSION=$(java -version 2>&1 | grep "java version")
if echo "$VERSION" | grep "1.8.0_33";  then
  NO ERROR (not code, just place holder)
else
  ERROR (not code, just place holder)
fi
```

`grep` will exit with `0` if outputs any lines, so will execute that in the `if`, otherwise the code under the `else` will run.

Comment: Nope, this seems to always be true.

Comment: ...? What version of bash / grep are you using?

Comment: This should work fine (though you might want to use `\.` to avoid matching non-periods there).

Comment: Everything should be latest

Comment: Also technically `grep` exits with zero if it outputs any lines (not it any matched) this is the same for `grep` but inverted for `grep -v`.

Comment: @Atomiklan **Everything should be latest** is not very helpful for narrowing down why it doesn't work for you. This works fine where I've tested. Note that because there's no `not` condition in the `if` statement the `if` and `else` statements are reversed